# Как сделать локализацию для подключаемого пакета python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, locale, gettext

Есть django проект, в котором используется локализация (интернационализация или разные языки). Для джанги все хорошо описано в доках и удалось настроить. Но в проекте используется питоновский пакет, который устанавливается в систему и импортируется в некоторых местах по мере необходимости.

```
from aromodule import clChart as ch, clAnalyse as an
```

Пакет - это несколько питоновских модулей(файлов .py) с классами, реализующими всякие математические вычисления. Строки(слова) там тоже есть и я хочу чтобы пакет возвращал все в той локали, которая в данный момент активна в джанго. В самом пакете локализация пока не предусмотрена, собственно в том и вопрос, что там надо сделать чтобы все заработало. Может в `__init__.py` что-то добавить?

Comment: если грубо, то : оберни вывод переменных из пакета в геттекст и локализуй как обычно через переводы в джанго.

Comment: так не пойдет. Нужно именно сделать локализацию внутри пакета, а я не знаю как.

Comment: поэтому и говорю - локализуй снаружи. внутри пакета надо вникать в чужой код. а так - также как в джанго описанно.

Comment: пакет тоже мой. Код не проблема. Мне сам принцип нужен, как локализовать. В инете горы примеров, но не получается разобраться.

Comment: from django.conf import settings импортировали, settings.LANGUAGE_CODE - узнали что написано, дальше в зависимости от значения подключаем нужный файл локализации.